# XCode Project Navigator Bug

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

Recently, while developing an app for iOS, XCode has begun to exhibit buggy behavior that hasn't gone away even after reinstalling my entire Mac (which leads me to believe that something in the project settings may be causing this).  In the left panel, switching to a pane other than the Project Navigator then switching back to it causes Project Navigator to expand ALL of the folders in my project.  In addition, if I attempt to make a new group by right clicking and selecting New Group, a new folder shows up momentarily, then disappears again.  The .pbxproj file is modified as well, but the new folder doesn't show up even if I restart XCode.  Has anyone been able to fix this before?  I wasn't able to find any posts anywhere relevant to this (it's kind of a hard problem to Google...).  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same bug in the XCode 9, which makes me really sad. Is there any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I tested the bug by creating another app; the new app didn't have these issues, so I concluded that the project I made must have been corrupted somehow.  I deleted and re-cloned the project from GitHub, which fixed the problem.  Something went wrong with Xcode's settings for my project; I'm curious as to what the problem was, so if anyone has had experience please let me know!